# Analog of Picard's theorem for Fractional Differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I need an analog of Picard's theorem of existence and uniqueness of solutions. The theorem is to be applied to linear fractional order differential equations with constants coefficients. 
I don't want the more general result because I need a 'simple' proof of the theorem.

I have not found such result.

Any idea? 
Any type of help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489846/fractional-calculus